# Not able to connect to irc.freenode.net on XChat IRC client in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: irc, xchat

I am facing problems connecting to the Freenode IRC server on my XChat IRC client. My service provider is [Tikona](http://tikona.in/). I have to go to a proxy 1.254.254.254, enter my login credentials and then I am connected to the Internet.

The XChat client was working for me when I was on an open proxy connection yesterday which does not required any such credentials. It sometimes connects but then again disconnects immediately. And sometimes, it shows fewer users who are connected to the channel (whereas the browser based client shows much more users).

Please let me know if there are any additional settings that need to be done when I am using an Internet connection that needs such login credentials. Or is the problem something else? Please help.

Comment: Freenode is having issues at the moment.

Comment: @dobey: I see, but the web based client works perfectly. Both are connecting to the same server, isn't it?

Comment: @bpositive: Not necessarily. There are around 25 servers (full list [here](http://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml)) for Freenode. One is selected depending on your location, load, and some other factors.

Comment: Why is this marked as off-topic? I am asking a question related to a package (XChat) which has been installed on "Ubuntu 13.04". If this is an off-topic question, then where do I ask these type of questions? Please guide me :)

Answer (score 1):

Freenode is having a huge DDoS right now, it should be fixed soonish.